# Change Activity layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my app i want to change the Activity `contentview` if a button was clicked for example.

In the begining i call the first layou:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.catalog);
    }
```

and when a button was pressed i call this one:

```
    public void showItemActivity(int position){
        setContentView(R.layout.item_view);
    }
```

and in this method my app crash.

i need to say that if i try this method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.item_view);
```

in the begin of another Activity it work perfectly, but it reali important for me that it will be in the same `Activity`.

## Edit

the logchat error msg:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Comment: your app crash and Why are you not put Logcat Error in question ...we are not magician

Comment: my logchat stay clean without any msg

Comment: in android its Sure if your app crash that have logcat error ,,,

Comment: If your logcat is clean, you're probably not listening to the emulator. Switch to DDMS View and target the emulator you're using. Then you're logcat shouldn't be so clean when your application crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your activity class may have extended ListActivity, and you should have a ListView whose id attribute is `android.R.id.list` in your layout xml file, so that your ListActivty class can find the main list of this activity.(if someClass extends ListActivity, it means that someClass, mainly has the role of a list). Just set your ListView id to `android.R.id.list` in `layout/item_view.xml`.